# I don't understand the need for self-joins. Can someone please explain them to me?

Tags: sql

```
 SELECT region, name, population 
 FROM bbc x 
 WHERE population <= ALL (SELECT population FROM bbc y WHERE y.region=x.region AND population>0)
```

I dont understand the logic of x and y using for the same table.

Comment: So you can look for other rows in the same table. In this case it looks like it's finding the smallest row for a given region by population by comparing each row to all other rows for the same region.

Answer (score 2):

x and y are taking to be two different instances of table bbc, To list a table two times in the same query, you must provide a table alias for at least one of instance of the table name. This table alias helps the query processor determine whether columns should present data from the right or left version of the table.

Answer (score 1):

This query returns all regions with smalest population in each rgion. To make this query without self-join you'll need to do 2 queries for each region:
1.

```
set @min=Select min(population) from bbc where population>0 and region=@region
```

2.

```
select region, name, population from bbc where population=@min and region=@region
```